# Exercise Petersen, Affine Connection, Riemannian Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am currently working with Riemannian geometry by Peter Petersen. I am wondering if someone can provide feedback on my proof of the exercise if it is correct or wrong.

Q.
Show that the connection on Euclidean space is the only affine
connection such that $\nabla X = 0$ for all constant vector fields $X$.

An attempt:

Let $X = \alpha^{i} \partial_i$ such that $\alpha^{i}$ is constant vector fields. Then for all $j$ we have with regard to the derivative $\nabla X = 0$ implies

$$
0 = \nabla X = \nabla_{\partial_{j}}X = \nabla_{\partial_{j}}(\alpha^{i} \partial_i)
= (\partial_{j} \alpha^{i})\partial_{i} + \alpha^{i}(\nabla_{\partial_{j}}\partial_{j})
= \alpha^{i} \nabla_{\partial_j} \partial_{i}
= \alpha^{i} \Gamma^{k}_{ij} \partial_{k},
$$
since the christoffel symbols of second kind is always zero by the fact of $g_{ij} = \delta^{i}_{j}$ and the directional derivative on this metric is zero. Hence
$$
0 = \nabla X = \alpha^{i} \Gamma^{k}_{ij} \partial_{k} = 0,
$$
we have shown that the affine connections is therefore flat.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks essentially correct. I don't know what is a christoffel symbol of the second kind, but your argument seems fine over all. I would add towards the end that the $\alpha^i$ are arbitrary. Just a remark on the exposition only.

Comment: Note that an affine connection need not be associated to a Riemannian metric and the difference between 2 affine connections is a tensor.

Comment: Thanks! I I meant with the Christoffel symbol of the second kind according to Petersens book and wolfram alphas dictionary who mention it: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChristoffelSymboloftheSecondKind.html

Comment: I don't understand what you are assuming and what your conclusion is. Are you assuming that $X$ is constant and $\nabla X = 0$? If so, what is your conclusion? Or are you assuming the Christoffel symbols are $0$? If so, what is your conclusion?

Comment: I assumed that $X$ is a constant (smooth) vector field, i.e. $X = \sum_{i} \alpha^{i} \partial_{i}$ ,so that I caculate its directional derivative in order to show its affine connection is zero. Later in the calculation, after using the fundamental theorem of Riemannian geometry, the christoffel symbol in the euclidean space is always 0. Therefore I concluded that the connection for $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the affine connection for some constant vector field $\alpha^{i}$ defined in the exercise.

Comment: Ok, I see some confusion. Let me try to clear it a bit. Given two affine connections on a smooth manifold, their difference is a tensor, with two indices down and one index up. On $\mathbb{R}^n$, you have the "standard" connection, say $\partial$, associated to the standard flat Euclidean metric. The affine connection $\nabla$ can thus be written as $\nabla = \partial + \Gamma$. Now use the hypothesis and deduce that $\nabla$ is nothing but $\partial$. Somehow, your formula is almost correct actually, but at this stage, proceed carefully to make sure the concepts are a 100% clear.